# Applications on Fedora are slow when connected to some networks

Tags: networking

I have a new laptop with Fedora 23 installed. I found that some various applications (Firefox, IntelliJ IDEA) are *really*, unnaturally slow when I am connected to our company's network. When I disconnect the network (or I am connected to a different network), everything is OK.

"Slow" means that application start takes minutes when there is no data in them (no tabs in Firefox, no project in IDEA). Once they are started, the performance is OK. I expect that they are trying to connect to the Internet during the boot.

It is weird that even logging in my **locally installed** Oracle is also slow (it takes minutes) but once I am logged in, `select`s seem to have good performance.

What do you think? What should I check? I don't know much about networking so I am not sure where to start...

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that there was missing my hostname in `/etc/hosts`...